# Meteor/angularjs project webview is white screen

Tags: angularjs

i have project in angularjs/meteos, when i try to run it and navigate myself to localhost:3000 it just returns me white screen, after doing CTRL + J (on chrome) it returned me these errors.

```
modules.js:4296 Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).provider(...).info is not a function
    at modules.js:4296
    at angular-sanitize.js (modules.js:4495)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:180)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:109)
    at meteorInstall.node_modules.angular-sanitize.index.js (modules.js:3677)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:180)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:109)
    at meteorInstall.client.lib.app.js (app.js:5366)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:180)
    at require (modules-runtime.js:109)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I don't use Angular, but do you have installed all crucial **NPM** and **atmosphere** packages?

Comment: Yeah, double checked aswell.